# Study association between continuous and categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, association-measure

I have independent continuous variables like `Age`, `Price` and outcome variable like `purchased` or `not purchased`

I know if we have continuous variables on input and output, we can use `pearson correlation` or `chi-square` test if both input and output are `categorical`.

Now, which test should I use to test the association of `continuous input variable` with `categorical outcome variable`?

I already referred [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169217/association-between-discrete-variables-and-continuous-variable) but there is no response.

So, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a binary outcome just use [logistic](/questions/tagged/logistic) regression. There are already very many posts at this site, so search for more information.

If you want more specific advice, you need to update (edit) your post with specific information.

Comment: I have only two input continuous variable. Should i still use log reg? Can't i individually test the association ofone inputvariable to the outcome variable? Can log reg work with1 input variable and 1 outputvariable? ..upvoted

Comment: halvorsen - can't we use point biseral coorelation?

Comment: Well, maybe, it depends on your goal. Why do you think logistic regression is not a good soultion?

Comment: Am happy to use logistic regression. But due to my lack of experience, i don't know whether logistic regression can be applied to estimate the relationship between one input variable amd one binary output variable?

Comment: If logistic regression can be used for one input and one binary output variable, may I know what is the use of point biseral correlation then? When to use point biseral correlation? How is it dofferent from logostic regression?

Comment: LOgistic regression is very flexible. You can use it with any number of input variables, continuous or binary or ... and one binary output variable

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please help me with the below? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/556061/linear-regression-for-longitudinal-data